# Use instance variables defined in model to a record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a users table which has first_name, last_name. I have defined full_name in the user model as below

```
def full_name
    [first_name, last_name].join(' ')
end
```

Is there a way I can use full_name to find a record in rails console like

```
User.find_by(full_name: "Jack Astor")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider creating your own function like:

```
def find_by_full_name(name)
  where("first_name || ' ' || last_name = ?", name).first
end
```

If you really want to use find_by(:full_name), you will have to monkey path find_by:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
   def self.find_by(*args)
     if args.first.key?(:full_name)
       where("first_name || ' ' || last_name = ?", args.first[:full_name]).where(args.first.except(:full_name)).take
     else
       super(*args)
     end
   end
end
```